# How do I use DataSet instead of DataReader

Tags: asp.net

```
dconnetion = New OdbcConnection(lsconnectionstring)
        dconnetion.Open()
        mssql = "select cust_id,cust_name,cust_address,cust_contact_no from cust_details where cust_id in (select cust_id from cust_details)"
        cmd.Connection = dconnetion
        cmd.CommandText = mssql
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

I use this statement to read data from a database using DataReader.

The problem is that when I use DataSet instead of DataReader what will the query is?

Comment: There wont be any change in the query, instead of reading to datareader you will need to use data adapter and fill the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DataAdapter.Fill()` method with the same query.

```
dconnetion = new OdbcConnection(lsconnectionstring);
//dconnetion.Open()
mssql = "select cust_id,cust_name,cust_address,cust_contact_no from cust_details where cust_id in (select cust_id from cust_details)";
cmd.Connection = dconnetion;
cmd.CommandText = mssql;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

using (OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)) 
{
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   dconnetion.Open();
   da.Fill(ds);
   dconnetion.Close(); 
}
```